# Problem about bounded sets in a metric space

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

There is a question in the chapter 2 about convergence, section 2.4 about bounded sets of the book "Topology of Metric Space" by Kumaresan.

Exercise 2.4.14 Let $G$ be a subgroup of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{C}$* of the non-zero complex numbers. Assume that as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ it is bounded. Show that $|g| = 1$ for all $g \in G$.

I try proof this, but I unfortunately have not had much progress.

g = a + b$i$ $\in$ $\mathbb{C}$*

I assume that metric is $d(g,\overline{g})$ = $|g|$ = $\sqrt{z * \overline{z}}$ = $\sqrt{(a+bi)*(a-bi)}$ = $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} > 0$

and I assumed that $G$ is a bounded set, so $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} < \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, but now I don't know how to use the definition of bounded set to show that $|g| = 1$ for all $g \in G$.

P.S.1: Sorry if there are some english errors, but I don't know english very well.

P.S.2: Sorry if there others errors about the format of my post I'm new here and I'm trying learn how post here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there is a $g\in G$ such that $|g| =c > 1$

Then, as $G$ is a multiplicative group, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \ g^n \in G$, but $|g^n| = c^n \to +\infty$, so $G$ can't be bounded

Now suppose there is a $g\in G$ such that $|g| = c < 1$

Then, as $G$ is a multiplicative group, $g^{-1} \in G$ and $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \ (g^{-1})^n \in G$, but $|(g$^{-1})^n| = c^{-n} \to +\infty$ so $G$ can't be bounded

Comment: I understood, thank you!